# Effective scroll in hibernate: session.evict vs session.clear vs CacheMode.IGNORE

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider a typical task, when we have to build huge file report, by scrolling appropriate results from DB. ORM framework is `Hibernate`.
We know, that there are 3 ways, how to avoid `OutOfMemoryException` for such pattern:

1. Use `session.evict(...)`:

   ```
   ScrollableResults customers = session.createQuery("from Customers order by id").scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
   while (customers.next()) {
       Customer customer = (Customer) customers.get(0);
       addDataToReport(customer);
       session.evict(customer);
   }
   ```
2. Use `session.clear()`:

   ```
   ScrollableResults customers = session.createQuery("from Customers order by id").scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
   int i = 0;
   while (customers.next()) {
       Customer customer = (Customer) customers.get(0);
       addDataToReport(customer);
       if ( ++i % 1000 == 0) session.clear();
   }
   ```
3. Use `CacheMode.IGNORE`:

   ```
   ScrollableResults customers = session.createQuery("from Customers order by id").setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
   while (customers.next()) {
       Customer customer = (Customer) customers.get(0);
       addDataToReport(customer);
   }
   ```

**So, the question is**: which of these methods is most better (in sense of performance) for mentioned purposes? Or may be there are more effective other methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `CacheMode.IGNORE` has nothing to do with your problem. It's about 2nd level cache, not session cache.
- `evict()` doesn't evict related entities if relationship is configured without `CascadeType.DETACH` or `CascadeType.ALL`. It means that:

  1. Related entities without cascaded eviction will accumulate in memory
  2. Related entities with cascaded eviction will be reloaded on each iteration, even if the are the same
- Threfore approach with `clear()` is the best option:

  1. When invoked, it evicts all entities from the session cache
  2. It's not invoked on each iteration, so that you can leverage session cache for related entities

Comment: Thanks for your response! And what about `StatelessSession`?

Comment: Yes, `StatelessSession` is an option too, but as far as I understand it would behave like `evict()` with cascading, therefore related entities won't be cached.

Comment: Thanks again. One more question, please :) If we will compare `StatelessSession` and `evict()` approaches - which one will be more efficient in performance point?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `StatelessSession`, but as long as don't need features that require stateful solution, the stateless one should always perform better.

Answer (score -1):

About the `evict()` and `StatelessSession`,

they both can optimize the memory usage to prevent loading whole data into memory.

The main difference is that `evict()` can still benefit from Hibernate features such as 2-level cache, lazy loading etc.,

whereas `StatelessSession` is Hibernate all-feature-disabled way. It relies on JDBC, which gives better memory optimization than `evict()`, but more suitable for the read-only scenario (As Entity in `StatelessSession` way requires explicit maintain by programmer).

When use either of them, programmer need to be careful when dealing with the Entity's status, Flushing timing, Connection & Transaction creation and their Lifecycle etc..

For more details, please see this blog:
https://dzone.com/articles/bulk-fetching-hibernate